# Cassandra cql shell script

Tags: shell, cassandra, cqlsh

I'm having an issue with a simple script here. Just can't find documented help that resolves my issue.

Here is my script.

```
#!/bin/bash 

$VCOPS_BASE/cassandra/apache-cassandra-2.1.8/bin/cqlsh --ssl --cqlshrc  $VCOPS_BASE/user/conf/cassandra/cqlshrc 

-e "cql_statement;"
```

I left out the cql for simplicity's sake, but everytime I run my file from the command line I simply enter the cql shell.

--execute and echo don't work either and I'm really not sure why I would need to save the cql statement to another file.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because `-e` is a cqlsh option, not a bash command that stands on its own.  Therefore, it needs to be on the *same* line as your `cqlsh` command.

```
#!/bin/bash 

$VCOPS_BASE/cassandra/apache-cassandra-2.1.8/bin/cqlsh --ssl --cqlshrc $VCOPS_BASE/user/conf/cassandra/cqlshrc -e "cql_statement;"
```

I tested this out with a simpler version:

```
aploetz@dockingBay94:~/scripts$ cat getEmail.sh
#!/bin/bash

cqlsh -u cassandra -p cassandra -e "SELECT * FROm stackoverflow.users_by_email WHERe email='mreynolds@serenity.com';"

aploetz@dockingBay94:~/scripts$ ./getEmail.sh 

 email                  | id                                   | username
------------------------+--------------------------------------+----------
 mreynolds@serenity.com | d8e57eb4-c837-4bd7-9fd7-855497861faf |      Mal

(1 rows)
aploetz@dockingBay94:~/scripts$
```

Comment: Yep, that's it. Thanks for helping a simpleton.

Comment: @PA_Commons No worries, I'm just glad I could help!